# Git for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, git

Does anyone know how I can run Git on Windows XP? I have inherited an XP VM and need a way to version my code.

Unfortunately updating is not an option due to license constraints

Comment: Can't you just download and use it? https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: if it's just a VM for compilation then use git in your host and then compile in the VM

Answer (score 28):

The last versions working with Windows XP (32 bit):

- **TortoiseGit 1.8.16.0** (https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/1.8.16.0/)

> This is the last version which is compatible with Windows XP and
>   Server 2003.

- **Git 2.10.0** (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.0.windows.1)

> As of Git for Windows v2.10.1, Windows Vista or later are required.
>   The last version of Git for Windows to support Windows XP and Windows
>   Server 2003 is v2.10.0. ([more](https://git-for-windows.github.io/requirements.html))

Answer (score 5):

This is an old article but hopefully answers a way to install on Windows XP

http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/08/19/install-git-for-windows-xp-windows-7/

> The only reason to install TortoiseGit is if you are used to
> TortoiseCVS/TortoiseSVN and want to keep the same look and feel.
>
> I use the following version for installation on Windows XP:
>
> - TortoiseGit 1.7.2.0 32-bit
> - Git 1.7.4
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official answer from the Git for Windows [Prerequisites](https://gitforwindows.org/requirements.html) page:

> ## Windows version
>
> As of Git for Windows v2.10.1, Windows Vista or later are required. The last version of Git for Windows to support Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 is [v2.10.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.0.windows.1).
>
> ## Why?
>
> Parts of Git are implemented in shell script, and Git for Windows runs those scripts via [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/)'s POSIX emulation layer, which in turn is based on the [Cygwin POSIX emulation layer](https://cygwin.com/). Seeing as Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 are years past their official end of life, the Cygwin project ended their Herculean efforts to support those Windows versions.

Digging into some GitHub issues suggests that there was no conscious decision on the part of GfW to drop support, but an MSYS update broke compatibility, and they realised at some point after the subsequent release (2.10.1).

- [Procedure entry point CancelSynchronousIo could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/906)
- [Git 2.10.1 32-bit doesn't work on Windows XP](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/911)
- [Teach the installer to refuse installing Git for Windows on XP or 2003](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/928)
- [can't run msys2_shell.cmd on xp: CancelSynchronousIo could not be located](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/687)

Comment: @Downvoter, sorry if this wasn't helpful to you.  I just wanted to get to an ultimate explanation of why support was dropped, I didn't find the ultimate answer, but I published what I did find, and cited as much as I could.